# How to log SQL requests posted by a django application?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have a quite slow admin interface in a django application, the application is supported by apache2 and PostgreSQL.

I suspect the problem to be unoptimized sql request but I cannot understand which one. I believe that a request is sent for every row instead of a request for all row.

Is it possible to log every sql requests actually sent to my database?

Thank for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `log_min_duration` option in the configuration file:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT

You might also want to install the auto-explain module which will also dump the execution plan of the slow queries to the log file.

More details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html

Comment: in /etc/postgresql/X.X/main/postgresql.conf, then restart postgresql